# Minor Bug in UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, ios6, constraints, frame

I have finally been able to get my app updated with constraints and Autolayout. However, now I'm having some weird behavior. My app flips over to a page where I have my settings, but when I return the pagination in the scroll view is wacky. It looks like it gets stuck between pages upon firing `viewWillAppear`. I had it log the contentOffset. When the bug occurs, it actually reports the offset to be 0.000000 when it has not yet scrolled all the way back. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Have not resolved it yet ...

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one. Still working on it!

Comment: I have a scrollview of width 320 with one child view (content view) of width 960. I have paging setup. If I'm on page 0 (contentOffset.x = 0), pushing (flip) + dismiss controller works fine and returns to a scrollview in the correct state. If I'm on page 1 (contentOffset.x = 320), push+dismiss causes the content view to be position off by 160 px. The frame x offset of the content view is -160 (incorrect). If on page 2, push+dismiss causes the frame x offset to be -320. This happens somewhere bewteen viewDidLayout and viewDidAppear

Comment: registering an observer on "center" on my contentView, I can see that the center property is changed incorrectly in UIScrollView layoutSubviews:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at long last I decided to set a variable to be the UIScrollView offset on `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and return to it on `viewWillAppear`. I still have a problem with the images in the ScrollView, but I attribute that to the constraints at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a hacky workaround to resolve my problem. I still do not install the core issue.

Basically, I just revert the changes made to center of my contentView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_contentView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == _contentView && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"center"]) {
        if (!_ignoreNextChange) {
            _ignoreNextChange = YES;
            _contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _contentView.frame.size.width, _contentView.frame.size.height);
        }
        _ignoreNextChange = NO;
    }
}
```